# how can I move domains to an AWS ELB who are currently assigned to a static Elastic IP without changing DNS on their registrar

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-ip

I have a large list of domains (which I do not control the domain registry for as they are clients).  I would like to route their traffic through an AWS ELB and upgrade their infrastructure, however asking them all to change DNS in their registrar is not really an option.  It seems like I'd want to assign the current elastic IP address the domains point to to the ELB, however this doesn't seem to be an option.  Is there a way I might be able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Elastic IP address can only be assigned to an Elastic Network Interface, which itself can only be assigned to an EC2 instance, not an ELB.

An ELB endpoint is effectively a DNS name with multiple A records that are used in round-robin, so you'll need to update DNS to point to the endpoint's CNAME if you want to use an ELB.

Comment: I realize you can't assign an elastic ip to an ELB, I'm just wondering if there's some 'trick' I might be able to do as coordinating a DNS change with around 100 different clients at the same time is not really an option.  I unfortunately inherited this setup, and I'd like to start moving it forward by using an ELB and using Chef for server setups and deployments.

Comment: Sadly not. You can create your own ELB using an EC2 instance and something like HAproxy, but there is no way to use an ELB without updating DNS.

Comment: that's unfortunate, guess I'll probably just leave the old server up while I wait for people to transition.  Thanks for the confirmation!